# i keep getting undefined for the objects created and expected an identifier when initializing the constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, undefined, identifier

I've done all the coding but I'm getting errors. for both objects created item1 and item2 it says undefined and for the constructor is says expected an identifier.

Inventory.h

```
#ifndef Inventory
#define Inventory

class Inventory{
private:
    string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;

public:
    Inventory(); //constructor

    string getName();
    double getPrice();
    int getQuantity();

    void setName(string);
    void setPrice(double);
    void setQuantity(int);

    double totalPrice();
    int decreaseQuantity(int);
    int increaseQuantity(int);
    void displayItemData();

};
#endif
```

inventory.cpp

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 Inventory::Inventory(){
    name="null";
    price=0.0;
    quantity=0;
}

string Inventory::getName(){
    return name;
}

double Inventory::getPrice(){
    return price;
}

int Inventory::getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

void Inventory::setName(string N){
     N = name;
}

void Inventory::setPrice(double P){
    P = price;
}

void Inventory::setQuantity(int Q){
    Q = quantity;
}

double Inventory::totalPrice(){
    return price*quantity;
}

int Inventory::decreaseQuantity(int x){
    return quantity-x;
}

int Inventory::increaseQuantity(int x){
    return quantity+x;
}

void Inventory::displayItemData(){
    cout<<"Name\tPrice\tQuantity\tTotal"<<endl;
    cout<<getName()<<getPrice()<<getQuantity()<<totalPrice()<<endl;
}
```

test.cpp

```
int main(){

Inventory item1, item2;
item1.setName("Keyboard");
item1.setPrice(23.5);
item1.setQuantity(12);

item2.setName("Speakers");
item2.setPrice(48.0);
item2.setQuantity(4);

item1.displayItemData();
item2.displayItemData();

item1.decreseQuantity(2);
item2.decreseQuantity(5);

item1.increaseQuantity(20);
cout<<"Total price of item 1: "<<item1.totalPrice()<<endl;
cout<<"Total price of item 2: "<<item2.totalPrice()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malformed include guard. Your `#define Inventory` means that the preprocessor will replace every instance of `Inventory` with the empty token.

Use:

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
// ...
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you :) solved that problem... but now its giving me an error under setName and getName in the cpp file saying declaration is incompatible.

Comment: Your `Inventory.h` should include <string> and use `std::string` instead of just `string`. BTW, all three of your set functions got the assignment backwards, and your `main.cpp` spelled `decrease` incorrectly.

Comment: @user3626095 _'but now its giving me an error under ...'_ There may be other flaws in your code, that would require different questions ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `#pragma once` instead of header guards.

**Pros**

- Your header will be always compatible with any other that can define same guard name too.
- You don`t have to make redundant definitions.
- You don`t have to write painful directives both on begin and the very end of every header file.
- You make your compile time shorter.

**Cons**

- It`s non–standard, but widely supported preprocessor directive.

**Conclusion**

If you want to get rid of all these redundant requirements about header guard from the past millennium, and don`t bother about stricte standards (hey! standards are for people, not people for standards), just use `#pragma once` directive and forget about any futher unpleasantnesses about obsolescent header guards.

Comment: I upvoted T.C.`s answer too as it is the best answer, but had to write about this alternative as I missed it in T.C.\`s answer above.